# How can I remove all the spaces in the cells of excelsheet using nodejs code

Tags: node.js, excel, space, createfile

I have an excel sheet with lots of spaces in between the content in each cell. I would like to keep that cell unaffected, so I would like to create a copy of the same and remove all the spaces of cell content. Is it possible to do from a nodejs code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do so using `xlsx` package from npm.

copy the File via node

```
const fs = require('fs');
fs.copyFile('source.xlsx', 'newFile.xlsx', (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
});
```

read the File to any Format you like with `xlsx` (code simplified):

```
XLSX = require('xlsx');
workbook = XLSX.read('newFile.xlsx', {type: 'binary'});
let worksheet = workbook.Sheets[workbook.SheetNames[0]];
initialData = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet);
console.log('initialData ')
```

now you have the first worksheet of your copied file as JSON and can perform whatever changes you like.

After using eg `trim` on every object you can write that JSON back to an Excel File

```
let workbook1 = XLSX.utils.book_new();
let worksheet1 = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet();
XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(workbook1, worksheet1, 'WorksheetName');
XLSX.writeFile(workbook1, 'newFile.xlsx');
```

The first step is optional as you are only working inside the JSON copy an writing a new file afterwards, but I mentioned it as it was in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

If you meant to remove the leading and the trailing white spaces, then this function should trim the white spaces from the header and all cells.

Please test it thoroughly before using it for production:

```
function trim_cells(ws) {
var range = XLSX.utils.decode_range(ws["!ref"]);
  for (var R = range.s.r; R <= range.e.r; ++R) {
    for (var C = range.s.c; C <= range.e.c; ++C) {
      var coord = XLSX.utils.encode_cell({ r: R, c: C }),
        cell = ws[coord];
      if (!cell || !cell.v) continue;
      // clean up raw value of string cells
      if (cell.t == "s") cell.v = cell.v.trim();
      // clean up formatted text
      if (cell.w) cell.w = cell.w.trim();
    }
  }
}
```

Note - The above solution is found in the GitHub [issue](https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs/issues/443#issuecomment-284133965).

For more information on how to pass an excel worksheet (passed as a parameter) to the above function please look at the [official GitHub link](https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs).